How would I keep the edge of this material smooth/rounded?
I'm assigning different colors to specific Face Loops for my tire here. You can see how the assigned materials smoothly wrap around the circular tire with a Subdivision Surface modifier. Those white strips are the tire's treads and they are separate model for now, they're lined up so they will merge perfectly with the tire's vertices once joined.

My problem is when I join the models together and merge the vertices, the red strip (right above the yellow) straightens out and isn't very rounded anymore, at least on top.

Thought maybe Sharpening or Clamping the edges would do something, didn't work. I've noticed after applying the Subdivision modifier those edges straightened out and warped, so the material does the same.

How can I keep the material's edge rounded while still merging the treads and tire as one? I've had this problem a few different times now and could never really figure it out.
Added the blend file if you wanna check it out. 

instead of merging, did u try boolean modifier union?

please share your blend file so we can investigate else we need to close for lack of details because there might be some technical details that cannot be seen in these pictutres.

I tried a boolean as Chris suggested but I didn't help me much. I ended up baking the material as a texture first and then merging the treads with the tire after and it seemed to do the trick. It worked but I still wish there was a different way I could go about it, I feel I have more control using materials instead of textures. I'm still open to suggestions.
